# How to increment a label by 1 if player1 Intersect with list of player2?

Tags: c#

I am doing a Tron Game, where I am trying to increment a label Score by 1 when player1 Intersect with body of player2 (list of players2). I have tried almost everything but any of it did not work. There is Score1() and Score2() method that adds 1 when I kill second player but second time it does nothing.

```
Player player1;
Player player2;
List<Player> players1 = new List<Player>();
List<Player> players2 = new List<Player>();

public void SetPlayer1() {
            var size = new Size(13, 13);
            var location = new Point(pbCanvas.Width - pbCanvas.Width / 3, pbCanvas.Size.Height / 2);

            player1 = new Player(Brushes.Red, size, location, 3);
        }
        
        public void SetPlayer2() {
            var size = new Size(13, 13);
            var location = new Point(pbCanvas.Width / 3, pbCanvas.Size.Height / 2);

            player2 = new Player(Brushes.Blue, size, location, 3);
        }

private void Score1() {
            var displayScore = 0;

            displayScore++;
            label1.Text = "Red Score: " + displayScore;
        }

        private void Score2() {
            var displayScore = 0;

            displayScore++;
            label2.Text = "Blue Score: " + displayScore;
        }

private void HandleCollision() {
            var players1Delete = new List<Player>();
            var players2Delete = new List<Player>();

            foreach (var item in players1) {
                if (player2.Intersect(item.Rectangle)) {
                    players2Delete.Add(item);
                    Score1();
                }
                if (player1.Intersect(item.Rectangle)) {
                    players1Delete.Add(item);
                    Score2();
                }
            }

            foreach (var item in players2) {
                if (player1.Intersect(item.Rectangle)) {
                    players1Delete.Add(item);
                    Score2();
                }
                if (player2.Intersect(item.Rectangle)) {
                    players2Delete.Add(item);
                    Score1();
                }
            }

            foreach (var item in players1Delete) {
                if (item is Player) {
                    players1.Clear();
                    players2.Clear();
                    SetPlayer1();
                    SetPlayer2();
                    position = Position.Null;
                    position1 = Position1.Null;
                }
            }

            foreach (var item in players2Delete) {
                if (item is Player) {
                    players2.Clear();
                    players1.Clear();
                    SetPlayer2();
                    SetPlayer1();
                    position1 = Position1.Null;
                    position = Position.Null;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your `players1Delete` and `players2Delete` lists are initially empty, but right after creating them you attempt to delete from them. Were you actually intending to copy `players1` and and `players2`?

Comment: "... and Score2() crash my game."  You have an **infinite loop** in there that doesn't actually do anything since `if (displayScore < playerScore) {` never triggers.  Both of those values are local variables set to zero...

Comment: Since your "playerScore" variables are **local** to each `ScoreX()` method, they will always start out at ZERO since they are created and reset each time those methods are called.  You most likely need to move those variables out to CLASS level so they can retain their values across calls...

Comment: I edited little bit a question could you pls help me?

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at `Score1()`:

```
private void Score1() {
    var displayScore = 0;

    displayScore++;
    label1.Text = "Red Score: " + displayScore;
}
```

You declare "displayScore" as a LOCAL variable.  This mean it only exists in `Score1()`, and it will get re-created each time you run `Score1()`.  You set its value to zero, then immediately increment it by 1.  In effect, every time you run `Score1()` the score for Red will be changed to 1.  That's the only result you'll ever get; the score for Red can only ever be 1!

Move that variable out to CLASS level so that it persists between calls.  Since you have both a Red and a Blue score we need to differentiate between those two values.
Here I've changed from "displayScore" to "redScore":

```
private int redScore = 0;

private void Score1() {
    redScore++;
    label1.Text = "Red Score: " + redScore;
}
```

Now everytime `Score1()` is run, 1 will be added to the previous score and the label will be updated.  Since "redScore" is at CLASS level it will retain its value.

You'd need to do a similar thing with `Score2()` and a different variable to track the Blue score.

```
private int blueScore = 0;

private void Score2() {
    blueScore ++;
    label2.Text = "Blue Score: " + blueScore ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried it out and when I hit second player it gives a random number maybe it is because When I hit a second players tail it gives its count. Tail is made of players List

Comment: I haven't looked at your intersection/collision code at all.  I was simply addressing your main concern, which was: "There is Score1() and Score2() method that adds 1 when I kill second player but second time it does nothing."  If your Red/Blue scores are now changing, then that issue is solved. Open up a new question that better explains the collision portion to answer that side.